# Understanding b:defaultwidgetversion='2' on Blogger Template

Tags: javascript, html, xml, templates, blogger

I'm trying to update a classic blogger theme using some of the new template expressions but applying b:defaultwidgetversion='2' to

```
<html ></html>
```

breaks up the comments area.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html b:css='false' b:defaultwidgetversion='2' b:layoutsVersion='3' b:responsive='true' b:templateUrl='fancy.xml' b:templateVersion='1.3.0' expr:dir='data:blog.languageDirection' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xmlns:b='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/b' xmlns:data='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/data' xmlns:expr='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/expr'>
```

Removing b:defaultwidgetversion='2' solves the problem but it's not updating the widgets to a newer version

Answer (score 0):

I think you should bring back that **b:defaultwidgetversion='2'** again and then after that add the default markup to successfully update the widgets to a newer version.

You can find the default markup after `]]></b:skin>` in any *version 3* theme

1. Just open any *version 3* theme (from an old blog or a testing blog).
2. Click on **CTRL + F** and in the search bar that will appear, type: `<b:defaultmarkups>` .
3. You'll find the code, copy everything: from `<b:defaultmarkups>` to `</b:defaultmarkups>`
4. Go back to the HTML of your current blog and paste it after `]]></b:skin>`

You can read the following article, it contains more details on how to update the layout to version 3: [Click Here](https://www.bloggerspice.com/2017/03/blogger-layout-widget-update.html)